# Open Start Menu on Monitor Where Cursor was when Key was Pressed

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 Pro x64 with a double monitor configuration, and I would like to have the Start Menu open on the window where the cursor was located when I press the Windows key. At the moment, when I press the Windows key, the menu always opens on the primary monitor. How could I modify this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I am using open-shell for this.

[Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu) it's on github. It does change your Start menu look quite a bit, but maybe there is an option to keep the default look and functionality and only enable one feature.

The feature you are looking for is in the settings -> Windows 10 Settings -> Open Windows Start menu on monitor with the mouse

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Currently, the only way I've been able to do this is using the [Actual Multiple Monitors](https://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/) application. Though I'm looking for a way to do it via script.